# How can I check if an object (that I have to insert in a list) is already in the list using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I am not so into **C#** and **.NET**. I have the following problem.

In my code I have something like this:

```
UOR uor;

foreach (int idUor in visibilitaPostRidistribuzioni)
{
    uor = UorSQL.GetUorFromId(siglaAOO, idUor, dbConfig);

    visibUtils.Uors.Add(uor);
}
```

where **visibUtils.Uors** is a list of **UOR** object.

As you can see I am iterating on a list of ID (**visibilitaPostRidistribuzioni**). For each ID I am retrieving an **UOR uor** object and I am adding it to the **visibUtils.Uors** list.

What I need is a smart way to check if this **uor** object exist in the **visibUtils.Uors** list before insert it to avoid duplication.

2 UOR object are the same object if they have the same values for these 2 fields: **SiglaAOO** and **SiglaUOR**

An **UOR** object is a model class like this:

```
public class UOR
{
    private string unitaOperativaResponsabile;

    public string UnitaOperativaResponsabile
    {
        get { return unitaOperativaResponsabile; }
        set { unitaOperativaResponsabile = value; }
    }
    private string areaOrganizzativaOmogenea;

    public string AreaOrganizzativaOmogenea
    {
        get { return areaOrganizzativaOmogenea; }
        set { areaOrganizzativaOmogenea = value; }
    }
    private string siglaAOO;

    public string SiglaAOO
    {
        get { return siglaAOO; }
        set { siglaAOO = value; }
    }
    private string siglaUOR;

    public string SiglaUOR
    {
        get { return siglaUOR; }
        set { siglaUOR = value; }
    }
    private int idUor;

    public int IdUor
    {
        get { return idUor; }
        set { idUor = value; }
    }

    private bool attiva;

    public bool Attiva
    {
        get
        {
            return attiva;
        }

        set
        {
            attiva = value;
        }
    }

    private int alias;

    public int Alias
    {
        get
        {
            return alias;
        }

        set
        {
            alias = value;
        }
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {

        // Get the hash code for the Textual field if it is not null.
        int hashTextual = siglaAOO == null ? 0 : siglaAOO.GetHashCode();

        // Get the hash code for the Digital field.
        int hashDigital = idUor.GetHashCode();

        // Calculate the hash code for the object.
        return hashDigital ^ hashTextual;
    }

    public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
    {
        // If parameter is null return false.
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // If parameter cannot be cast to Point return false.
        UOR p = obj as UOR;
        if ((System.Object)p == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Return true if the fields match:
        return (idUor == p.idUor) && (siglaAOO.Equals(p.siglaAOO));
    }

    public bool Equals(UOR p)
    {
        // If parameter is null return false:
        if ((object)p == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Return true if the fields match:
        return (idUor == p.idUor) && (siglaAOO.Equals(p.siglaAOO));
    }
}
```

I know that I can iterate on the **visibUtils.Uors** list and check if in this list exist an object having the same **SiglaAOO** and **SiglaUOR** fields value if the current object that I have to insert.

But...exist some smarter way? (maybe something related to lambda expression)

Comment: Use [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__). Either way you have to iterate the List. If you want a `n log n` function then you need to use a `Dictionary`

Comment: You've already overridden GetHasCode and Equals, so that is fine. You can then use [`List.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=netframework-4.8), but that would be exactly "iterate on the visibUtils.Uors list and check". A smarter way is to use a [hashset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.8) instead of a list, where `Add` would simply return false if the object is already present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have `GetHashCode` and `Equals` defined, it's better to use `HashSet<UOR>` rather than `List<UOR>`. Because `HashSet` will check for existence with `O(1)` complexity, while `List` - with `O(n)`.

```
var interimSet = new HashSet<UOR>();
foreach (int idUor in visibilitaPostRidistribuzioni)
{
    var uor = UorSQL.GetUorFromId(siglaAOO, idUor, dbConfig);

    interimSet.Add(uor); //which is the same as: if(!interimSet.Contains(uor))interimSet.Add(uor);
}

visibUtils.Uors = interimSet.ToList();
```

Comment: You don't even need `Contains`. `Add` will already [not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.add?view=netframework-4.8#returns) add duplicates.

Comment: @GSerg, that's absolutely right, thank you. I've improved my answer

Answer (score 1):

Change this to the following:

```
foreach (int idUor in visibilitaPostRidistribuzioni)
{
    var uor = UorSQL.GetUorFromId(siglaAOO, idUor, dbConfig);
    if(!visibUtils.Uors.Any(a => a.Equals(uor))
    {
        visibUtils.Uors.Add(uor);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's `uor` that must be not present, not `idUor`.

Comment: Changed answer to reflect this, now using the Equals already implemented

Answer (score 1):

```
    UOR uor;
    foreach (int idUor in visibilitaPostRidistribuzioni)
   {
      var uor = UorSQL.GetUorFromId(siglaAOO, idUor, dbConfig);
      if(!visibUtils.Uors.FirstOrDefault(a => a == uor)
      {
        visibUtils.Uors.Add(uor);
      }
  }
```